# Images not appearing when loading offline without packager

Tags: react-native

As the title suggests, `<Image src={require('...')} />` does not appear when attempting to view while offline and disconnected from react native packager.

Comment: Possibly you are trying to get an image that is on an external server, in this case to be the opposite then you would need to see your code to know more or less what is happening to you

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that either because of the `<TouchableOpacity>` or the lack thereof `<View>` wrapping the `<Image/>`, it causes the image to not appear.

So the first example doesn't work:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
    <Image src={require('...')} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

whereas this does:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
    <View>
      <Image src={require('...')} />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```